# Can I get RealSense to not re-allocate memory at every irritation of a loop?

Tags: c++, 3d, camera, depth, realsense

For example:

```
rs2::frameset data;
rs2::align align_to_color(RS2_STREAM_COLOR);

for(;;) {
    data = rs2_pipe.wait_for_frames();
    data = align_to_color.process(data);

    rs2::depth_frame depth = data.get_depth_frame();
    rs2::video_frame color = data.get_color_frame();
    ...
}
```

would presumably de-allocate and re-allocate memory for the `depth` and `color` at every frame. How can I get this camera to dump frames into the same memory location every time to optimize?

Comment: *How can I get this camera to dump frames into the same memory location every time to optimize?* -- Maybe the compiler's heap manager already optimizes this.

Comment: It seems it sometimes goes into the same location and sometimes not. I check with
```
    std::cout << "depth ptr = " << (uint64_t)(void*)depth.get_data() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "color ptr = " << (uint64_t)(void*)color.get_data() << std::endl;
```
The results are not always in consistent memory locations.

Comment: Make sure that you test an optimized build, not a "debug" or unoptimized build.  The C++ heap allocator is smart enough to find the same space again, if no other heap allocation occurred.

Comment: Actually the depth one stays relatively stable, the color one flip flops between a couple of values.

Comment: I'm using release and -O3

Comment: set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -Wextra")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3")

Comment: I would trust the allocator being smart.  Note that a good allocator will only need to do  minimal work to find a free block that has already been deallocated.  There may not be any real calls to the OS allocation functions being done (except for maybe on the first iteration of the loop).